# how to divide a spectogram into a certain number of ranges using mel filter banks using matlab?

Tags: matlab

how to divide a speech spectogram into a certain number of ranges using mel filter banks using matlab???basically i have to divide the spectogram into 25*25 blocks...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the (free) [auditory toolbox](http://cobweb.ecn.purdue.edu/~malcolm/interval/1998-010/) implements mel filter banks. Have a look at the documentation.